# How does this ISR routine work?

Tags: c++, debugging, arduino-uno, atmega

I at the moment trying to write an the step signal for an stepper motor, and recently found out that atmel had written this [application note](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8017.pdf), 
and provided some code that purpose. The signal i have to provide my motor, is a pulse modulated signal, where the frequency of the signal determines, the speed, rather than the 4 pin signal which they provide. The code is available on [github](https://github.com/plastiv/stepper-motor-controller/blob/master/%20stepper-motor-controller%20--username%20plastiv%40gmail.com/code/speed_cntr.c) (link).

But i am currently questioning ISR routine which controls all the stages of the motor (Stop, acceleration, run ,deceleration). 
More specifically how it keeps track of the step_count which is in charge of changing the state.

```
#pragma vector=TIMER1_COMPA_vect
__interrupt void speed_cntr_TIMER1_COMPA_interrupt( void )
{
  // Holds next delay period.
  unsigned int new_step_delay;
  // Remember the last step delay used when accelrating.
  static int last_accel_delay;
  // Counting steps when moving.
  static unsigned int step_count = 0;
  // Keep track of remainder from new_step-delay calculation to incrase accurancy
  static unsigned int rest = 0;

  OCR1A = srd.step_delay;

  switch(srd.run_state) {
    case STOP:
      step_count = 0;
      rest = 0;
      // Stop Timer/Counter 1.
      TCCR1B &= ~((1<<CS12)|(1<<CS11)|(1<<CS10));
      status.running = FALSE;
      break;

    case ACCEL:
      sm_driver_StepCounter(srd.dir);
      step_count++;
      srd.accel_count++;
      new_step_delay = srd.step_delay - (((2 * (long)srd.step_delay) + rest)/(4 * srd.accel_count + 1));
      rest = ((2 * (long)srd.step_delay)+rest)%(4 * srd.accel_count + 1);
      // Chech if we should start decelration.
      if(step_count >= srd.decel_start) {
        srd.accel_count = srd.decel_val;
        srd.run_state = DECEL;
      }
      // Chech if we hitted max speed.
      else if(new_step_delay <= srd.min_delay) {
        last_accel_delay = new_step_delay;
        new_step_delay = srd.min_delay;
        rest = 0;
        srd.run_state = RUN;
      }
      break;

    case RUN:
      sm_driver_StepCounter(srd.dir);
      step_count++;
      new_step_delay = srd.min_delay;
      // Chech if we should start decelration.
      if(step_count >= srd.decel_start) {
        srd.accel_count = srd.decel_val;
        // Start decelration with same delay as accel ended with.
        new_step_delay = last_accel_delay;
        srd.run_state = DECEL;
      }
      break;

    case DECEL:
      sm_driver_StepCounter(srd.dir);
      step_count++;
      srd.accel_count++;
      new_step_delay = srd.step_delay - (((2 * (long)srd.step_delay) + rest)/(4 * srd.accel_count + 1));
      rest = ((2 * (long)srd.step_delay)+rest)%(4 * srd.accel_count + 1);
      // Check if we at last step
      if(srd.accel_count >= 0){
        srd.run_state = STOP;
      }
      break;
  }
  srd.step_delay = new_step_delay;
}
```

As it looks to me, is the step_count being set to zero at the begining of the ISR and the incremented in either state ACCEL,RUN or DECEL.

A quick debug does show that the variable increment to the value i desire it to be, but I really cannot figure out how.

I know missing something very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These three variables are static.  That means they will only be initialized once:

```
// Remember the last step delay used when accelrating.
static int last_accel_delay;
// Counting steps when moving.
static unsigned int step_count = 0;
// Keep track of remainder from new_step-delay calculation to incrase accurancy
static unsigned int rest = 0;
```

If you follow the code you'll find that they are used to keep state from one interrupt to the next.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how `static` works when it is applied to a function local variable.

That `static unsigned int step_count = 0;` means that the first time into the function `step_count` is set to 0. It does not get set every time into the function.

The `static` means it isn't a stack variable, it is in the same memory space as a global variable, except that it can only be accessed inside the function that declares it.

Comment: Yeah.. I had to read it a bit more carefully thanks anyway :)